# Pytest Finalizers - order of execution

Tags: pytest

I am writing py.test program, considering the following py.test fixture code:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def my_fixture(request):
    def fin1():
        print("fin1")
request.addfinalizer(fin1)
    def fin2():
        print("fin2")
request.addfinalizer(fin2)
```

What the execution order? I didn't find any mentions on the documentation regarding the execution order of finalizers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the easiest way would be to just try running your code with `-s` and see in which order the prints happen.

What I'd recommend is to use yield fixtures instead, so you can explicitly control the teardown order easily:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class")
def my_fixture():
    # do setup
    yield
    fin1()
    fin2()
```

Starting with pytest 3.0 (which will be released soon), this will also work by just using `yield` with the normal `@pytest.fixture` decorator, and will be the recommended way of doing teardown.