# Can we have multiple addfinalizer in pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to add multiple finalizer functions in pytest, so is it possible to add more than one addfinalizer. if yes then what will be the sequence of execution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can add more than one finalizer. From the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code):

> Both yield and addfinalizer methods work similarly by calling their code after the test ends, but addfinalizer has two key differences over yield:
>
> 1. It is possible to register multiple finalizer functions.
> 2. Finalizers will always be called regardless if the fixture setup code raises an exception. This is handy to properly close all resources created by a fixture even if one of them fails to be created/acquired:

This question is very similar to [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665397/pytest-finalizers-order-of-execution), where the question of order is discussed (and a better solution is offered).